# USB not showing up as boot option

Tags: boot, usb, 14.04

I just bought an Asus X551 that came with Windows DOS which I'm not familiar with. I had installed ubuntu on my former laptop but I did it on windows 7. I followed the instructions I found and created a bootable USB drive but it doesn't show as a boot option. Please help.

Comment: Could you please clarify? Windows is an operating system, MS-DOS/PC-DOS are operating systems. Windows took over DOS as the main operating system for Microsoft around Windows '95-Windows 2000 era for personal computers. You would set up your boot options in the BIOS of the computer (by pressing a key like F2, F8, F10, DEL, or other key) then go into boot options and set the boot order of the USB drive to a higher priority slot (usually 1, or on top)

Comment: I think it's FreeDOS. The USB drive isn't even showing up in the boot order list.

Comment: Just in case, make sure the USB is inserted (and it is bootable), if not check your Motherboard specs and see if it has the capabilities to boot from USB. (MOST do, but some are weird)

Comment: I formatted the USB and re-did it to make sure it's bootable and it worked :D .. thank you :)

Comment: Could you use my answer as solved then? :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows is an operating system, MS-DOS/PC-DOS are operating systems. Windows took over DOS as the main operating system for Microsoft around Windows '95-Windows 2000 era for personal computers. You would set up your boot options in the BIOS of the computer (by pressing a key like F2, F8, F10, DEL, or other key) then go into boot options and set the boot order of the USB drive to a higher priority slot (usually 1, or on top).

Just in case, make sure the USB is inserted (and it is bootable), if not check your Motherboard specs and see if it has the capabilities to boot from USB. (MOST do, but some are weird)